# immersive slider does not allow page scrolling on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I'm using the immersive slider plugin but when I use it by mobile and I try to go down the page to see the rest of the site with the touch it does not allow. Has anyone experienced this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#immersive_slider").immersive_slider({
            container: ".main"
        });
    });

</script>
<!-- //banner -->
```

Comment: You need to provide more (code) information in order to get some help.

Comment: Okay, I put the slide javascript code